# How do I undo the problems caused by doing an 'svn commit -m "bla" ' on multiple files

Tags: svn, version-control

I have performed an svn commit on multiple files by mistake by typing 'svn commit -m "message"' in the top repo directory instead of typing the relevant filename after it. This means that the commit message is wrong for most of the committed files and I wasn't ready to commit some files either.

I now have one revision number for many files and it appears that I have just one svn log entry for that single commit.

I have found that it is possible to change this single log entry but I really want to have a different commit message for each file which I wanted to commit.

Is there any way of sorting out this mess or do I have to change the single commit message and then change a comment on each individual file and commit it again with a new message and accept that this is a compromise?

Comment: Why can not you revert your commit and do it again?
1) svn merge -c -previous_revision..

2) svn commit -m "revert wrong commit."

Comment: If I did that I think I would lose the changes in the files. Did you mean `svn merge -c -2302` when the catastrophic commit was revision number 2303?